Implementing LaTeX?
Quite often, I find the need to include mathematical expressions, and currently it is very awkward to typeset them. (I typically use fixed-width mode for that since is looks a bit better.) Could we enable LaTeX?

I just asked around a bit, apparently MathJax is enabled on a per site basis per request.
Unfortunately, it also has significant impact on page load and display times, though, so we'll have to look into it some more.
Until then, I found that there are some websites that convert Latex to images, which one can then add to a post. The SE engine allows for upload to and linking from imgur.com. It is not quite as convenient, but does the job quite well. I have been using codecogs:eqneditor for this purpose.
example:


This is basically it, show us a hand full (like 10+) posts where having it would have saved a significant amount of work for the contributor, and we'll probably enable it.

I would have liked it in my answer here. But I think Murchs website was a good replacement, although I didn't think of it at the time.

This is declined, for now - but we're happy to revisit the idea if you're able to show us a decently-sized group of posts that would have been significantly better if it had been enabled. If you've got a chunk (say 10 - 12 +) where you're trying to bend ascii and images into shapes they just weren't intended to form, and MathJax could alleviate that problem, we're happy to take a look.
It's a non-trivial performance hit (most with fast connections won't realize it), and once it's on, it's nearly impossible to turn off, as you'd have to go back through every single use of it and make it work otherwise. 
Feel free to just add another answer to this if the need clearly arises, and we'll have a look.
