Should MathJax be enabled on cryptocurrency sites?
Even Code Review, Game Development, furthermore, World Building has MathJax "Latex rendering". I believe it'd be really useful if it was enabled on Bitcoin SE.
For the full list: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/360277
Possible uses
1) Elliptic curves: I know $dG$, how can I find $d$
2) Amounts paid: Alice has $5$ dollars
3) Tables
4) Selfish mining formulae: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}\cdot\begin{cases}(q/p)^{z-k} &  k \leq z\1 & k >z\end{cases}$
Note: If you're going to enable it, don't enable $, we need that as dollars. \$ would be great.
Answers: What can be added to the list above?

related: https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/648/5406, https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/563/5406
